# vc++ compile error RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am getting following error while building my vc++ project (Using visual studio 2010)

RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for

I know there is some issue while building resources but how to get the exact problem area?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2005? If that's the case, [this question on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/9cdaa780-cc97-498b-815e-cf23c3f3b333/) might apply to you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned about the Visual Studio version, it's VS 2010.

Comment: Where do you get the error? While the program is running or when you compile?

Comment: There's an rc.command.x.tlog file in the build directory that shows the arguments passed to rc.exe.  Post it here if you can't sort it out.

Comment: @Александър Александров I am getting this error building my vc++ project. It's not at runtime.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solution:
Add a slash to the last include path will do the trick.
If your last include path already contain a slash at the end, delete it will also work.

**Note:** Some other include paths can cause this too; it doesn't have to be the very last include path. In particular, check the last include path that you *add* (in addition to the built-in ones) in your project/properties file.

Comment: particularly amazing!

Comment: Still true and fix works years later in VS 2017. Thank you

Comment: I so much love this solution!

Comment: This still is the solution... Had a '\' at the end of my last include path, removing it did the job. Thank you!

Comment: January 24, 2021 This is still a bug in Visual C++ 2019. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean? If my last include is: `#include <time.h>` , I need to add `#include <time.h>\\` ` ? it will cause compilation error. Also in case you meant `#include <time.h\>` , also compilation error. Please explain with an example.

Comment: VS 2022 17.3.0 v1.1 still has this problem a decade later. Neither adding nor substracting the '/' has solved it for me. Time to try and isolate it and report it for real to MS's dev community. I'll put a link back here if I succeed.

Comment: Found a dev comm link: [RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for Help](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/rc-fatal-error-rc1107-invalid-usage-use-rc-for-hel/470075).

Comment: I added to the VS dev community site: [RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for Help](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/RC-:-fatal-error-RC1107:-invalid-usage;/10065552?entry=myfeedback&ref=native&refTime=1654778530833&refUserId=a79af35b-706a-4ad7-a54a-ff938ed18116). A day later, MS VS closed it un-fixed and no plans to fix it or even address it.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. I solved it removing the trailing backslash from the last path in `Include Directories` (from `Project Properties | Configuration Properties | VC++ Directories`).

Comment: In my case this issue started to occur on a newly-created project, after I had added BOOST environment variable to the include paths of Visual Studio (tools->options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories). As I was using a variable, I just added `\.` to the end, which seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

I got this when upgrading from VS2008 to VS2010. None of the suggested solutions worked for me.
What worked for me was deleting all the files in the configuration build folder (e.g. Release) and rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I also solved this problem by removing VS include path "\" from last entry.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for VS2010: 
`click menu "Project","Properties"` to open Property pages. 
`click "Configuration properties", "general"` to change Output Directory from `"$(Configuration)\ \"` to `"$(Configuration)\"` ,change interminably directory from `"$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\ \"` to `"$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\"`.recompile and it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced that both with VS2015 and VS2017 .
Pls look in  [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3277580d-75f7-4a6f-8ac6-c18f7b0ca0b6/resource-compiler-error-rc1107?forum=vssetup), at the answer of AH214.

In some cases the Resource Compiler fails to understand the options of the RC command line  created by Visual Studio .

To find the problematic option do:

1. In VS2015, as described by AH214, copy the command line options listed in Project -> properties -> Configuration Properties -> Resources -> Command Line .
2. Find some *.rc file on your machine.
3. Open Visual Studio command prompt.
4. Issue the command

   > RC [the options copied in (1)] [the path to the rc file in (2)] .

   You should get the same RC1107 error.
5. Check in this property page the contents of ...Resources -> All
    Options . Look for a suspicious option and fix or remove it.
6. Repeat (4) and (5) till you do not get the RC1107 error in (4).

   Once you found the culprit, check if you can change it or even remove
   it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with VS 2017. The problem was that I did not notice that I had the build configuration set to Release and there was a string in one of the controls that was too long and needed to be truncated by the resource editor when the resources were loaded. Putting the build configuration back to Debug and attempting to open the Resource file fixed it. I got a different message this time: string too long - truncated, and the resources could be viewed now.

Answer (score 0):

the backslash trick didnt work for me. but i just added a new icon to the RC file and then it worked all fine for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31103818)