# Can't open .rc files in Visual Studio for editing, app compiles fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I get the an RC1107 error when I try to open any RC for editing, but all my libraries and the app itself compile fine.

[image: Error dialog]

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912136/vc-compile-error-rc-fatal-error-rc1107-invalid-usage-use-rc-for), but besides not having any useful information, it seems to be a slightly different problem.

I've tried a number of things, from closing and reopening Visual Studio, to ensuring the integrity of the .rc and resource.h files by performing a diff with the previous version.  I've even tried rebooting my machine.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please, show us the complete .rc source. Open it "As Text"

Comment: A web search on RC1107 turns up a fair number of hits and they all seem to be caused by preprocessor definitions with quote characters.  For example, see the last post in this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/9cdaa780-cc97-498b-815e-cf23c3f3b333/

Comment: @kids_fox: You really want me to post a 7000+ line .rc which I'm not even allowed to show you?  Trust me on this, the .rc itself is fine.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I did the web search and didn't find anything useful.  That's why I'm asking here.  Also, none of my preprocessor defs have quotes in them.

Comment: @MBraedley, What happens if you add a new rc file to the project instead of this one?

Comment: @kids_fox: I get the same error.  For a library that doesn't already have resources, the .vcproj file is edited, and the resource.h and .rc files are created, but I still can't edit them in VS.  I get the same error as above.  A similar thing happens for libraries that do have resources, but the files obviously already exist.

Comment: @MBraedley: I don't see how you can be certain a 7000-line file and its project settings are perfectly correct, but if you can't post it then it's beside the point.  Does the same error occur on other machines?  If so, the file itself or the project settings are in error.  If not, your VS setup is the culprit and an uninstall/reinstall will likely fix it.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I know it's fine, because the project settings for some of the libraries haven't changed in a year, the file itself hasn't changed enough to cause this problem, and it was working fine last week.  The only thing I can think of that's changed on my system between everything working and now is some Windows updates.  I didn't see anything specific to VS, but who knows.

Comment: @MBraedley: So you're saying this doesn't happen on other machines?

Comment: @CareyGregory: Everything works fine on my boss's machine, and he hasn't done his Windows updates yet.

Comment: @MBraedley: I'm skeptical a Windows update caused this.  I would completely uninstall VS and reinstall it.  A pain, but you could easily spend as much time fiddling with it and never figure out what happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vc++ compile error RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912136/vc-compile-error-rc-fatal-error-rc1107-invalid-usage-use-rc-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question I linked to actually did contain the right answer, but was so vague as to be useless.  After some more searching, I found the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e4ef7904-0947-4792-aa4a-b28077146d02/), namely this response:

> I've had the same issue.
>
> It looks like the include path processing is broken in VS8. I
>   disassembled the resource compiler dll and found that the command line
>   being passed to rcdll.dll was corrupted. The last slash on the include
>   path was being replaced with a quote character. There was no starting
>   quote.
>
> To fix the problem, I made a minor change to the include paths in the
>   IDE.
>
> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories
>
> Show directories for: Include files
>
> I Added a slash to my last path, so "P:\" became "P:\\". Ok the
>   changes and the problem went away. :-)
>
> Hope this works for you.
>
> Andy

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I discovered in Visual Studio 2017 but it's possible to work in any previous version. It worked in a very weird manner. While having opened the Visual Studio with your project, go in File Explorer to the RC file in your project, right click and open with Visual Studio 2017. The RC file will be opened in the curent project and everything will work like a charm.